# Open html text in new tab using $window.open

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
$window.open('<span>request processed successfully</span>', '_blank');
```

I would like the `$window` service to show the simple text `request processed successfully` in a new tab.

But instead of it, it treats the html text as location url and tries to open the page `http://domain-addr#request processed successfully`

How can i pass html text argument to angular's `$window` service?

Comment: try reading the docs for [window.open()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this in standard JavaScript...

```
function newWindow() {
    // create some html elements
    var para = document.createElement('p');
    var title = document.createElement('title');

    // define some window attributes
    var features = 'width=400, height=400, status=1, menubar=1, location=0, left=100, top=100';
    var winName = 'New_Window';

    // populate the html elements
    para.textContent = 'Some example text.';
    title.textContent = 'New Window Title';

    // define a reference to the new window
    // and open it with defined attributes
    var winRef = window.open('', winName, features);

    // append the html elements to the head
    // and body of the new window
    winRef.document.head.appendChild(title);
    winRef.document.body.appendChild(para);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pure javascript,

```
var w = window.open("www.mydomain.com/test.php", "_blank");
w.document.write('<span>request processed successfully</span>');
```

Comment: Your answer would be more valuable if you'd include an explanation why the suggested approach solves the problem...

Comment: yep, but there is an approved answer

Comment: All the more reason to highlight why you feel your approach needed to be added to the mix, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

you could just create a simple html document with called success.htm or similar with "request processed successfully" and include that in the function.
so `$window.open('success.html','_blank', 'size blah blah');`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

**HTML:**

```
<button id="newWindow">
  Click
</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//call the function right away
(function() {
  //grab button by id
  var newWindow = document.getElementById("newWindow");
  //add an event listener 
  newWindow.addEventListener("click", function() {
    //create a new p element
    var p = document.createElement('p');
        // change the styles of your paragraph
    // optional
    p.style.color = "red";

    p.style.fontSize = "4em";
    //Insert the text you want
    p.textContent = "request processed successfully";
    //open the window
    var windRed = window.open('', '_blank');
    //append the p element to the new window's body
    windRed.document.body.appendChild(p);
  }, false);
})();
```