# JavaScript: Adding onClick to Div with URL as a Variable

Tags: javascript, onclick

The code below makes a Div for every object it finds in an array.  It then adds a header, a paragraph, an image, and an anchor.

The div's actually look like rectangles on top of one another.  What I would like to do is add an onclick attribute to the divs based on the keys within my objects ( coffeShops[i].menu).  When I do so though, clicking just doesn't do anything and i get this error message in console

"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'menu' of undefined"

This only happens when I try window.open with the object key coffeShops[i].menu.  If I swap that out with "http://www.google.com" it works just fine.  Also, the links from that variable show up in the console just fine.  So I know it's getting the data from the object just fine. But for some reason it doesn't want to open from the div.

FYI I'm extremely new to this so apologies if the explanation doesn't make sense.

```
    var containerDiv = document.getElementById("container");
    console.log(containerDiv);


   for (var i = 0; i < coffeeShops.length; i++){

      var launchMenu = function(){
        window.open(coffeeShops[i].menu);
      }

      console.log(coffeeShops[i].menu);

        var coffeeShopDiv = document.createElement("div");
        coffeeShopDiv.className = "coffeeShop";
        coffeeShopDiv.onclick = launchMenu;
        containerDiv.appendChild(coffeeShopDiv);

        var coffeeShopImage = document.createElement("img");
        coffeeShopImage.src = coffeeShops[i].image;
        coffeeShopImage.className = "coffeeImage";
        coffeeShopDiv.appendChild(coffeeShopImage);

        var coffeeShopHeader = document.createElement("h1");
        coffeeShopHeader.className = "coffeeHeader"
        coffeeShopHeader.innerHTML = coffeeShops[i].name;
        coffeeShopDiv.appendChild(coffeeShopHeader);

        var coffeeShopPar = document.createElement("p");
        coffeeShopPar.className = "coffeeDescription"
        coffeeShopPar.innerHTML = coffeeShops[i].description;
        coffeeShopDiv.appendChild(coffeeShopPar);

        var coffeeMenu = document.createElement("a");
        coffeeMenu.href = coffeeShops[i].menu;
        coffeeMenu.innerHTML = "MENU"
        coffeeShopDiv.appendChild(coffeeMenu);



    };
```

Comment: Can we see your HTML? Also, it looks like you are missing your object.

Comment: Are you sure, the coffeeShops object exists? From the error, it looks like coffeeShops is undefined.

Comment: My HTML has almost nothing in it but the standard html, body, head, style, etc.  Yes I'm 100% the object exists because they show up when I do console.log(coffeeShops[i].menu);

Comment: Also, if you see the bottom part of the JS, you'll see the link is using the same object and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED: in light of comment**

It looks like you need to separate the function which opens the new window from the code which generates page items.  By slightly restructuring your code this can be achieved by using the [`element.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) method.

```
/* place the 'launchMenu' outside of 
   the for-loop so it can be accessed
   by each of the target elements */

function launchMenu(event){
    /* get the class attribte of
       the clicked element */
    var clickedClass = event.target.className;
    var targetElement,
        link;
    /* is the clicked element the containing div? */
    if (clickClass !== 'coffeeShop') {
       /* nope */
       targetElement = event.target.parentNode;
    } else {
       /* yep */
       targetElement = event.target;
    }
    /* get 'data-url' of target */
    link = targetElement.getAttribute('data-url');
    /* open the new window */
    window.open(link);
}

/* elsewhere: create elements as before */
for (var i = 0; i < coffeeShops.length; i++){
    var coffeeShopDiv = document.createElement("div");
    coffeeShopDiv.className = "coffeeShop";
    /* add 'data-' attribute to target div */
    coffeeShopDiv.setAttribute('data-url', coffeeShops[i].menu);
    containerDiv.appendChild(coffeeShopDiv);

    var coffeeShopImage = document.createElement("img");
    coffeeShopImage.src = coffeeShops[i].image;
    coffeeShopImage.className = "coffeeImage";
    coffeeShopDiv.appendChild(coffeeShopImage);

    var coffeeShopHeader = document.createElement("h1");
    coffeeShopHeader.className = "coffeeHeader"
    coffeeShopHeader.innerHTML = coffeeShops[i].name;
    coffeeShopDiv.appendChild(coffeeShopHeader);

    var coffeeShopPar = document.createElement("p");
    coffeeShopPar.className = "coffeeDescription"
    coffeeShopPar.innerHTML = coffeeShops[i].description;
    coffeeShopDiv.appendChild(coffeeShopPar);

    var coffeeMenu = document.createElement("a");
    coffeeMenu.className = 'coffeeMenu';
    coffeeMenu.innerHTML = "MENU"
    coffeeShopDiv.appendChild(coffeeMenu);

    /* attach an eventListener to each
       created '.coffeeShopDiv' element */
    coffeeMenu.addEventListener(
        'click', launchMenu, false
    );   
};
```

The target element (`coffeeShopDiv`) now contains a url-reference in its 'data-url' attriubte and has an event listener assigned.

When the target element, or any of her child elements, are clicked the `launchMenu()` function will be invoked.  This function checks which element was clicked by comparing the `className` attribute to the class name of 'coffeeShopDiv' - such that if the class name of the clicked element is not 'coffeeShop' the `targetElement` variable is assigned to the clicked elements parent Node (that is, 'coffeShopDiv').

The 'data-url' reference is obtained and used in `window.open()`.

Also see:

- Using [`data-*`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes
- [Event.target](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target)
- [Quriksmode: Introduction to Events](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/introevents.html)
- [This StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34735823/4746328) about using
  `window.open()`

Comment: Hmm. So my code It think is confusing. I'm only using the var coffeeMenu (the anchor) as a stop gap.  I would like to completely delete that and be able to launch a link straight from clicking on any point of the div.  So basically, I want to click anywhere on the coffeeShopDiv and open the link. The link for each created will be different because it's pulling from a different object in that loop.

Comment: @Jake I've edited the code slightly so that clicking the containing div or any element inside it will trigger `window.open()` - hope that helps